# Is it possible to to re-initialize an object in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a class named insect child of sprite.I have created a 
instance of that class in GameLayer and then initialize with
it using,

`insect *bgg = [insect spriteWithFile:@"bird2a.gif"];`

then i set a timer(10 second) to change the image using

`*bgg = [insect spriteWithFile:@"2.gif"];`

but my program crashes.Now my question is it possible to 
re-initialize an object or it is immutable??

I have another question, when i used

`- (BOOL) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event

{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint point2 = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];`

```
CGPoint cpoint=[[Director sharedDirector] convertCoordinate:point2];
NSLog(@"In touch began");
```

}

in my insect class it cannot detect touch on  'bgg' object declared
in GameLayer.But when I used this function in GameLayer it can 
detect touch.

whats wrong with my approach??Plz someone explain.

Advanced thanx for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program crashes because you have a typo. Remove the '*' from '*bgg'. That means you are dereferencing the pointer, then trying to apply the creation of a new object to the dereferenced pointer. You just want

`bgg = [insect spriteWithFile:@"2.gif"];`

However, it's overkill to create an entirely new sprite just to change the image. A `Sprite` is a subclass of `TextureNode`, so just use TextureNode's `texture` property to give a Sprite a different image.

```
Texture2D *newImage = [[TextureMgr sharedTextureMgr] addImage:@"2.gif"];
bgg.texture = newImage;
```